# Rails 5 + Nested Attribute with has_one having errror on create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested

My Model Code

```
class Bank < ApplicationRecord
    has_one :address
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :address
end



 class Address < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :bank
 end
```

My Controller

```
def create
    @bank = Bank.new(bank_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @bank.save
        format.html { redirect_to @bank, notice: 'Bank was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @bank }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @bank.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
end

def bank_params
      params.require(:bank).permit(:code, :currency, :name, :mobile_1, :mobile_2, :email, address_attributes: [:id, :name, :area, :pin_code, :city_id] )
end
```

It's giving error something like that

**@messages={:"address.bank"=>["must exist"]}, @details={"address.bank"=>[{:error=>:blank}**

why it's showing reverse... not understanding

Comment: What does address model look like.  Seems to me you have validation on assess checking for bank and it looks like that is failing. Hence your seeing it in reverse

Answer (score 7):

I'm sure that's because there's a validation on your Address model for the bank. Whereas, based on observations, I think Rails tries to:

```
validate your parent model
validate your child model # validation fails here because parent doesn't have an id yet, because it hasn't been saved
save parent model
save child model
```

However, I think you should be able to solve this by using the `:inverse_of` option like so:

```
class Bank < ApplicationRecord
    has_one :address, inverse_of: :bank
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :address
end

class Address < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :bank, inverse_of: :address
  validates :bank, presence: true
end
```

Let me know if that works for you

Comment: Hello Sir... it solved my problem ... but i am still not understanding ... why inverse_of  required ???
May you help me on this doubt ?? It will be great help.

Comment: the `:inverse_of` option is largely for optimization. It basically says reference the in-memory object for associations. This is needed because while validating your child model, the associated object hasn't been saved and associated objects don't refer to in-memory objects by default.

Comment: Here's an article that could explain this better: https://www.viget.com/articles/exploring-the-inverse-of-option-on-rails-model-associations

Comment: This is because Rails 5 changed `belongs_to` associations to set the `required` attribute to default to `true`. You need `inverse_of` so that Rails can figure out the associated models correctly. http://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/02/15/rails-5-makes-belong-to-association-required-by-default.html

Comment: Thanks for that @LucaSpiller. I forgot to mention that in Rails 5.

Comment: Thanks  @LucaSpiller.

Comment: This should be the right answer considering setting parent association as :optional would not work for in many (probably most situations)

Answer (score 2):

**Rails 5 makes belongs_to association required by default**

```
By using (optional: true), we can change behavior 

class Bank < ApplicationRecord
    has_one :address, optional: true
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :address
end



 class Address < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :bank, optional: true
 end
```